# Link the edit page of a record to a table

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

Now I have a table in a VF that shows a bunch of leads. In this table I put the view button, when the users click the button they can view the record detail page, but how can I put near the view button the edit button?
here my code:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="output">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Possibili Lead" id="Possibili" rendered="{!IF(Lead.Company =null , false, true)}" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Lead" id="possibilita" collapsible="false" columns="1" >
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!PossibiliLead}" var="pl">
        <apex:column headerValue="Action">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!pl.Id}">View</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!pl.Id}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!pl.Company}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!pl.LastName}"/> 
        <apex:column value="{!pl.Email}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!pl.Phone}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!pl.Website}"/>                             
        </apex:pageblockTable>
```

With the edit button the user can open the edit page of the that lead and the fields prefilled with the actual values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code for opening the current record in standard edit mode:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Edit, pl.Id, null, true)}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

From your controller fill all the attributes and redirect the page like this

```
PageReference requestPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(new Lead(Id=<Lead Id>)).edit();
    return requestPage;
```